# RuntimeError: Exception occured in `Recorder` when calling event `after_batch`: iter.device(arg).is_cuda() INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-lightning, fast-ai

I having troublem deploying my CNN pytoch code on DNA sequence data.

Complete error message is :

```
RuntimeError: Exception occured in `Recorder` when calling event `after_batch`:
    iter.device(arg).is_cuda() INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loops.cuh":89, please
```

report a bug to PyTorch. argument 1: expected a CUDA device but found cpu

Given CNN model is :

```
# import the necessary packages
from torch.nn import Module,Dropout,Conv1d,Linear,MaxPool1d,ReLU,Conv2d,MaxPool2d
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torch import flatten
from typing import List
class model_test(nn.Module): # deepcre model  
def __init__(self,
             seq_len: int =1000,
             kernel_size: int = 8,
             p = 0.25): # drop out value 
    super().__init__()
    self.seq_len = seq_len
    # adjusting window size corresponding to sequence length 
    window_size = int(seq_len*(8/3000)) # 1000* = 2 
    # CNN module
    self.conv11 = Conv1d(4,64,kernel_size=(kernel_size), padding='same' )
    self.relu11 = ReLU()
    self.conv12 = Conv1d(64,64,kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')
    self.relu12 = ReLU()
    self.maxpool1 = MaxPool1d(kernel_size=window_size)
    self.Dropout1 = Dropout(p)
    #self.flatten = flatten()
    self.fc1 =Linear( 64*64*500 , 1)

def forward(self, x):
   # x = xb.permute(0,2,1).unsqueeze(1)
    """Forward pass."""
    print(x.size()) # 512 batch size x 1000 sequence length x 4 channel 
    print(x.dim())
    x = x.permute(0,2,1)
    print( "input : ",x.shape) # 512 batch size x 4 channel x 1000 sequence length 
    x = self.conv11(x)
    print(x.size()) 
    x = self.relu11(x)
    print(x.size()) 
    x = self.conv12(x)
    print("conv1 2nd : ",x.size())
    x = self.relu12(x)
    x = self.maxpool1(x)
    print("maxpool : ",x.size())
    x = self.Dropout1(x)
    x = x.view(batch_size_init, 64*500)
    x= x.view(-1)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    return x

def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch
    y_hat = self.model(x)
    loss = F.cross_entropy(y_hat, y)
    self.log("train_loss", loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

def configure_optimizers(self):
    return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.02)
```

I have tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68621210/runtimeerror-expected-a-cuda-device-type-for-generator-but-found-cpu/71780879#71780879) here to assign cuda in my data and even tried to assign my data loader directely to gpu. However I am having same error. Can anyone help me?